# Cannot run subprocess with my script after using Pyinstaller?

Tags: python, subprocess, pyinstaller

I have very `simple_script.py` that use subprocess.run for execution "external" command this kind `utility.exe "input_file" -o "output_file"`
My script is functioning just fine before being compiled with Pyinstaller in a single file. BTW, I'm using the following command to convert `simple_script.py` to `simple_script.exe`:

```
pyinstaller --onefile --add-binary "utility.exe;." simple_script.py
```

And my script looks like this:

```
import subprocess, os

print(os.listdir())
cls = 'utility "input_file " -o "output_file"'
command_execution = subprocess.run(cls, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

print(command_execution)
```

As you can see for the successful running of `simple_script.py` i have to have `simple_script.py` itself, `utility.exe`, and files to be processed.
But when I run a single-file version of my script (`utility.exe` included) in the directory with input file, I'm getting two strings output:

1. `['input_file', 'simple_script.exe']  # cause print(os.listdir()) command execution`
2. `CompletedProcess(args='utility.exe "input_file.txt" -o "output_file.txt"', returncode=1, stdout=b'',
       stderr=b"'utility.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external
       command,\r\noperable program or batch file.\r\n")`

#### As far as I understand, `utility.exe` is not extracted so, it cannot be reached and executed. So, the question is - what I'm doing wrong? Maybe I need something to make `utility.exe` file accessible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add function below to your script

```
def resource_path(relative):
    if hasattr(sys, '_MEIPASS'):
        return os.path.join(sys._MEIPASS, relative)
    else:
        return os.path.join(os.path.abspath("."), relative)
```

and use it to determine cls:

```
cls = resource_path('utility.exe') + ' "input_file" -o "output_file"'
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you very much.